# How to start a foreach loop with a specific value in PHP?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I need to start a for each loop at certain value, ex `foreach($somedata as $data)` Here I want to start doing some stuff only when the value of that data is "something"

I want to start doing something only after a specific value.

```
foreach($somedata as $data){
  if($data == 'Something'){
  //start processing, ignore all the before elements.
  }
}
```

I tried `break` `continue` nothing seems to work as I wanted

Comment: To clarify… Given `['foo', 'something', 'bar']`, you want to process `'something'` and `'bar'` but skip `'foo'`?

Comment: Yes! if $data = foo do nothing if $data = something, process loop from that point.

Comment: There is one more way to do it. Using array_keys you can get all key names in the array you can loop with the keys. But since there is already a very good answer here there is no point in writing it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a indicator variable to achieve this.

```
$starter = 0;
foreach($somedata as $data){
  if($data == 'Something'){
    $starter = 1;
  }
  if(starter == 1){
    //start processing, ignore all the before elements.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For clarity, it's probably better to pre-process your array before looping over it. That way the logic inside your loop can purely focus on what it's supposed to do.

```
$arr = ['foo', 'something', 'bar'];

$toProcess = array_slice($arr, array_search('something', $arr));

foreach ($toProcess as $element) {
    echo $element, PHP_EOL;
}
```

outputs

```
something
bar
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer (as of now).

Comment: This is the best answer for how to properly achieve what is trying to be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep a flag whether you have already encountered the desired value or not:

```
$skip = true;

foreach (... as $data) {
    if ($data == 'something') {
        $skip = false;
    }

    if ($skip) {
        continue;
    }

    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$skip = true;
foreach($somedata as $data){

  if($data == 'Something'){
    $skip = false;
  }

  if($skip) {
   continue;
  }

  //start processing, ignore all before $skip == false.
}
```

Comment: I Swear, i didn't copy any thing ... i was shocked... even variables have same names ;)

Comment: I saw the timing, I'm sure we both wrote the same thing independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the values only from the moment you identify one value, then you can use a flag :

```
$flag = false;
foreach($somedata as $data){
    if($flag OR $data == 'Something'){
        $flag = true;
        // processing some stuff
    }
}
```

Once the flag is reset to `true`, whatever the current value is, the content of your `if` will be executed.